# Does anybody know an alternative for php's `$a['mykey'][] = $a` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

Basically I want to push value or create an array and add value to a dynamically created key through a loop. I can do this neatly in Php using `[]` operator.

```
      foreach($array => $value){
           $ret['mykey'][] = $value
      }
```

This will create an array if not exist and push `$value` to it.
I am looking to do the same with JavaScript.

**Edit**
So far my approach is defining with a condition and then using array push.

```
    if(!ret['mykey']){
         ret['mykey] = []
    }
    ret['mykey'].push(value)
```

I am searching for replacement to this in one line statement.

PS: I believe objects are javascript's analogical replacement to PHP's associative array. Please correct me if I think wrong.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and where it goes wrong.

Comment: I've updated my approach in the question body. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. You make changes accordingly.

```
x = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array ) ? x : []

//or

var arr = arr || [];
```

Comment: This is defining if not defined. I am looking for something which magically defines and push value to an array if not defined in one statement. Somewhat like I suggested with PHP. Also I know I can do something like this: `if(!ret['mykey']) ret['mykey] = []` and then `ret['mykey'].push(value)`

Comment: @RishabhJha - You seem to already have an idea of how to do it? Please show us your attempt and explain where it fails.

Comment: Yes Sure, you can do that. It depends on your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing along the lines of ...

Check if index exists as key in object, if not the add it as key and assign it blank array.

```js
let a = {};
let index = 'mykey';
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (typeof a[index] == 'undefined' || !(a[index] instanceof Array))
        a[index] = [];
    a[index].push(i + 10);
}
console.log(a);
```